# Jekyll trying to post with angular js

Tags: angularjs, jekyll, github-pages

Trying to post via angular js in Jekyll. Is it possible?

```
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.formData = {"name":"myname", "mail":"mymail@mail.hu", "message":"msg"};

        $scope.sendContactSubmit = function() {
            var name_val = $scope.formData.name;
            var email_val = $scope.formData.mail;
            var message_val = $scope.formData.message;
            var jsondata = "{\"contact\": { \"name\": \"" + name_val + "\", \"email\": \"" + email_val + "\", \"message\": \"" + message_val + "\" }}";

            alert("click2 " + jsondata);

            $http({
                url: "xxx.com/api/contact",
                type: "POST",
                data: jsondata,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).success(function (data) {
                alert(data)
            });
    }
});
```

Here is my code. Til "click2" working, and then nothing happening. Can I use angular and http post in jekyll and github pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inject the `$http` to the controller

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
```

Also use `then` to catch the response. `success` is deprecated in new versions

```
 $http({
     url: "xxx.com/api/contact",
     method: "POST",
     data: jsondata,
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
 }).then(function(response) {
     alert(response.data)
 });
```

Comment: Almost done... It looks like it is now sending a GET instead a POST, and data become nothing...

Comment: {"contact": { "name": "myname", "email": "mymail@mail.hu", "message": "msg" }}

Comment: should be `method: "POST",` not type